# Coldfusion 10 supports <cfoauth> tag or not?

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, single-sign-on, coldfusion-10

Can somebody please tell me if Coldfusion 10 supports  **cfoauth** tag? Do I need to import anything for this?

Answer (score 2):

The `cfoauth` tag was added with ColdFusion 11. ColdFusion 10 does not support that tag.

[Refer to cfdocs.org for more information on the tag and the version 11 requirement](https://cfdocs.org/cfoauth)

- **ColdFusion 10 and ColdFusion 11 are no longer supported versions.**

Answer (score 2):

No, the tag is not supported in ColdFusion 10. [It was introduced in ColdFusion 11](https://cfdocs.org/cfoauth).

But [there is a convenient component available for older versions of ColdFusion](https://github.com/coldfumonkeh/oauth2).

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, Alex!  The base component that you mentioned is written in Lucee, can I directly download this and copy it into my code? My code is written in CF10.

Comment: Or is there any way to convert that base component into ColdFusion 10?

Comment: @Pragati The code should run just fine. Lucee is mostly compatible to Adobe's CFML and the author stated the component was tested with CF10.